# Have a Jquery selector that works, but does not work in $.post

Tags: jquery, post

I have this Jquery line which finds the cell I would like to input data into, This works when I use it outside of my $.post function (below), but not inside my $.post

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(".total_item_price").html("new text");
```

But when I use the above line in the below example, It does not work. It doesn't update the text in the required field.

```
$.post(url, { "params": value}, function(data) {

          // This is where I am having a problem
          // also tried .text and .val
          $(this).parent().parent().find(".total_item_price").html(data.total_price_item);

          alert(data.total_price_item); // This outputs my data
       }, "JSON");
```

I basically want to put my returned (data) into the  cell of the table. I don't think that my table structure is the issue, but I can post it if needed.

I should add, that I have to find the parents and field, because each post function will output into a different cell, so its relative to where the user clicked.

**Whats going wrong in this code?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `this` inside your load callback is not equal to `this` outside of your load callback. They have different scopes.

Before you call the post, cache the `this` from the other scope into a variable:

```
var scope = this;
```

And then in your callback you can reference the other `this` as `scope`:

```
$(scope).parent().parent().find(".total_item_price").html(data.total_price_item);
```

Answer (score 4):

In `$.post` `this` will not point to the same element which you are thinking. Please use the actual selector to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

because "this" in your function is a reference to the function and not to the node !

Answer (score 4):

`($this)` is not what you think it is! `this` is *always* the owner of the function being executed, which in the `$.post` is the **callback** function.

Answer (score 2):

you can  do it like this,

```
  var a= $(this);
  $.post(url, { "params": value}, function(data) {

          // This is where I am having a problem
          // also tried .text and .val
          a.parent().parent().find(".total_item_price").html(data.total_price_item);

          alert(data.total_price_item); // This outputs my data
       }, "JSON");
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` will not work there. As it is in the scope of the callback function, not the click event.

Assign `$(this)` to a variable outside of the post (inside the click event handler) and then use that inside the post callback.

```
  var that = $(this);
  $.post(url, { "params": value}, function(data) {
      that.parent().parent().find(".total_item_price").html(data.total_price_item);
      alert(data.total_price_item); // This outputs my data
  }, "JSON");
```